# MySQL query on multiple row with "where" cause?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Product table:

```
id  | name
100   A
101   B
102   C
```

ProductCategory table:

```
id | product_id | category_id
1    100          7
2    100          5
3    101          7
4    101          2
5    102          7
6    102          10
```

How can i get product_id that it's category_id have got 7 and 2?

Comment: I am new at sql sorry :/ i tried it with just where cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have products that have category 2 and 7 both then you can do so

```
select p.*
from products p
join ProductCategory c on(p.id = c.product_id )
where c.category_id in(2,7)
group by p.id
having count(distinct c.category_id) = 2
```

To have products that have category 2 or 7 then you can do so

```
select distinct p.*
from products p
join ProductCategory c on(p.id = c.product_id )
where c.category_id in(2,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i get product_id that it's category_id have got 7 and 2?

```
SELECT product_id
FROM ProductCategory
WHERE category_id IN (2, 7)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT category_id) = 2
```